# How can I print an stdClass object as a string?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am getting the following error when I try to print an array using the print_r command
Parse error: `syntax error, unexpected '$array' (T_VARIABLE) in /home4/rajatwalia/student.rwalia.com/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/shortcodes.php(66) : eval()'d code on line 6`

Here is the code that is written in a php shortcode plugin in wordpress

```
global $wpdb;
$profile_id = um_profile_id();
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE 
meta_key = 'student_id' AND user_id = $profile_id;" );
$array = json_decode(json_encode($result),true);
//$array[0] -> $studentid;  
print_r $array;
//print_r($result);
```

I am using json because otherwise my result is a stdClass and I want a String

Comment: What's the point of `json_decode(json_encode())`? If you want to convert a `stdclass` to an array, just cast it, ie `$array = (array) $result;`. In any case, `print_r` is a **function** and must be called like one, ie `print_r($array)`

Comment: You can also specifically ask for an array by using `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT...", 'ARRAY_A')`. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Comment: @Phil Now I get an array of stdclass objects with one entry, `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => 2330002 ) )` , is there a way to now convert this object into a string?

Comment: You mean like `foreach($result as $obj) echo $obj->meta_value;`? If so, yes?

Comment: @Phil, Yes sort of! I want to store that value 2330002 as a string in a new variable, not just `echo` it

Comment: It's already a string in a variable, ie `$obj->meta_value`. I'm not sure what else there is to do

Comment: Okay thank you for all your help. I think I am missing some basics in php, I will learn some more and then figure it out

Answer (score 1):

The print_r is a function is should be called like this:

```
print_r($array);
```

You can transform the class to string using the function serialize.

```
print_r(serialize($array));
```

Or if you want to get just the values of the array you can use the function implode:

```
print_r(implode(', ', $array));
```

This function will transform the values of the array in a string separated by comma. The first param of the implode is the separator and the second is the array that will be converted by string.

If you want to have both, name and value of array. You can do this:

```
//variable that will storage the string
$string = "";

/** this loop will run all the array, the $key variable will storage the name of 
 *the array position(the key), the $value variable will storage the value of the 
 *array in that position
 */
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $string .= $key . ": " . $value . ", ";
}

print_r($string);
```